# How can i scroll in a UIScrollView to a certain point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i scroll to a point (x,y) in a scroll view in an animated way (i.e. get to (x,y) in 1 second ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method, passing it a rectangle that you want to be visible after the scrolling has been completed.

You can read up more on this in the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you read Apple Docs ? Check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html .